# CakePHP 3 and SplTempFileObject

Tags: php, cakephp

I have installed League\Csv\Reader which uses SplTempFileObject and when run comes back with Error:

> Class 'App\Controller\SplTempFileObject' not found

I cant seem to find a Use statement, any help appreciated code below:

```
$writer = Writer::createFromFileObject(new SplTempFileObject());
```

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Do you have mbstring extension enabled in php?

Comment: Yes i do, CakePHP requires it

Answer (score 0):

PHP namespacing 101, you need to use `\SplTempFileObject` (backslash prefix) or add `use SplTempFileObject;` at top of file.